# Add context to render_to_response using decorators

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a view:

```
@add_value
my_view(request):
   render_to_response('template.html', {'var1' : 'value'})
```

and a decorator:

```
def add_value():

    def decorator(view_func):
        def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            #what code can I put in here to add { 'var2' : 'value' } to render_to_response context?
```

I would like the decorator to add a key pair, so the final render_to_response will become the following:

```
render_to_response('template.html', {'var1 : 'value', 'var2' : 'value'})
```

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can't with that view code, because the rendering has already been done by the time the function returns. You can return a [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/) instead, which will allow you to change the context, but you'd probably be better off using a context processor, as Bernhard's answer suggests.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible like you're trying to do it, as the view already returns a readymade `HttpResponse` object. But if you want to add something to the context of more than one view a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) might be what you are looking for:

```
def add_value_context_processor(request):
    return {'var': value}
```

And add it to [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) in your `settings.py`!